# How to force a series of inline objects to wrap with XEP RenderX XSLFO

Tags: xsl-fo

The following image is an extract from a PDF I generated via RenderX XEP. This fragment contains a series of hyperlinked keywords with padding between them. As is evident, the line is not wrapping and because of that the text of each word is compressed:

[image: compressed keywords]

The code that generates this block is:

```
     <fo:block-container wrap-option="wrap" space-after="10pt">
        <fo:block space-after="5pt">
             <fo:inline font-weight="bold">Keywords</fo:inline>
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block wrap-option="wrap" start-indent="20pt">
             <fo:inline padding-right="10pt">
                 <fo:basic-link color="blue" external-destination="http://example.com">Boat</fo:basic-link>
              </fo:inline>
              <fo:inline padding-right="10pt">
                  <fo:basic-link color="blue" external-destination="http://example.com">Dragon</fo:basic-link>
              </fo:inline>
               [...]
         </block>
     </fo:block-container>
```

I cannot identify the property that will allow the `fo:inline` objects to wrap. I attempted `keep-together="no"` on `fo:block` and on `fo:inline`, but they are not allowed.

What am I missing to allow this series of `inline`s to wrap?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: A work around: I inserted a space `&#32;` after each `fo:inline` which allows the formatter to wrap. But it's not elegant...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The padding doesn't count as a space, so the line-breaking algorithm has nothing to work with.

You could use `&#x200B;` to insert a ZERO-WIDTH SPACE instead of `&#32;` for a regular space.

You could instead use a 10pt space character:

```
<fo:basic-link color="blue" external-destination="http://example.com">Boat</fo:basic-link>
<fo:inline width="10pt"> </fo:inline>
```

(Don't include the line break in your generated XSL-FO, otherwise there'll be a regular space and a 10pt space in your output.)

Comment: Or backwards into the XSL you should put <xsl:text> </xsl:text> between the inlines or as Tony says insert a break character